# Angular auth guard async/subscription problems

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am using an auth guard to protect my routes. The problem I have is that if I want to access the homepage, I get redirected to the login from the auth guard. After I press login, I will get redirect to the return url and auth guard gets called again. Thats no problem but in this call, the user is still not set so I will stay at the login page. Pressing login a second time will fix this and redicrect me correctly.

Why is my user value still not set here?

auth.guard.ts:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const user = this.authenticationService.userValue;
    if (user) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User | null>;

public get userValue() {
    return this.userSubject.value;
}

login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment().apiUrl}/auth/login`, { username, password }, { withCredentials: true })
        .pipe(map(async (user) => {
            user.permissions = await this.getUserPermissions(user);
            this.userSubject.next(user);
            this.startRefreshTokenTimer();

            return user;
        }));
}
```

login.component.ts:

```
  onSubmit(data: {username: string, password: string}) {
    this.authService.login(data.username, data.password).pipe(first()).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';

        this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      },
    })
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Simplest solution is to add `console.log` after you set the subject in your login method and at the beginning of the guard. Also, are you using the user subject as an observable anywhere, because that subject seems unnecessary and could just be the user type itself. Otherwise I would replace subject with `new ReplaySubject<User>(1)`.

Comment: @Silvermind Yeah, the order is: `Not logged in. Redirect to login` => `Login done! Redirect to return url` => `Not logged in. Redirect to login` => `userSubject updated`. So the order is not right but I dont know why. And yes, I use the subject somewhere else

Comment: I notice now that you are returning a promise of user instead of the user, because of the `async` and `await`. Perhaps you should use a switchMap with the promise converted to an observable.

Comment: Oh yes. Thats the solution. I didn't saw that I was returning a promise and not the user itself.

Answer (score 1):

u should wait for the authGuard to authenticate the user, since you  are using async you return back to the login page before updating the value of user

```
  onSubmit(data: {username: string, password: string}) {
    this.authService.login(data.username, data.password).pipe(
        first(),
        tap(user => {
            const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
            this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
        })
    ).subscribe({
        error: (err) => {
            console.error(err);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Please write proper English in your answers. Non-native-English users may have problems understanding phrases like "u r". Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is meant to be a knowledge base. Answers aren't just for the one who askes a question but *mainly* for future readers.